# sizewithFont and drawinRect Formatting

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone app and each year some code elements generate deprecated issues. My app appears to run fine except for some slight format issues.  I've tried to use the suggested code, but it just result in errors.  I'd really like to fix these to see if solves the formatting issues.  Could someone help me with these.

First Issue:'sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:  Tried to use the suggested replacement, but it just resulted in an error (see code below).  Not sure where to fit the current code in the option, attributes, and context.

Second Issue:  'drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -drawInRect:withAttributes:  Tried to use the suggested replacement, but it just resulted in an error (see code below).   Not sure where to fit the current code re withAttributes.

```
 //Draw text fo our header.
        CGContextRef    currentContextHeader = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContextHeader, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0);

        NSString *textToDrawHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", enterSubject.text];

        UIFont *fontHeader = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];

        //Original Code that generated the issue
        //CGSize stringSizeHeader = [textToDrawHeader sizeWithFont:fontHeader constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(_pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, _pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        //Proposed change that resulted in an error
        CGSize stringSizeHeader = [textToDrawHeader boundingRectWithSize:fontHeader options:attributes:context:constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(_pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, _pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        CGRect renderingRectHeader = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, _pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSizeHeader.height);

        int ydistanceToLine = kBorderInset + kMarginInset + stringSizeHeader.height +kMarginInset;

        //Original Code that generated the issue
        //[textToDrawHeader drawInRect:renderingRectHeader withFont:fontHeader lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

        //Proposed change that resulted in an error
        [textToDrawHeader drawInRect:withAttributes:renderingRectHeader withFont:fontHeader lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

Comment: Did you read the warning messages? They tell you what to use instead. And please search on the messages. Those have been covered here many times.

Comment: I did search how to use the replacement, but it was not clear how to do that given the examples given.

Comment: [Edit] your question with actual code (not pictures) showing what you have tried to do. Explain clearly what issues you are having your attempt.

Comment: Share your code, in order to help you, but as say in the warnings you need to replace deprecated methods by new methods

Comment: Below is my code.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `-boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` is `CGRect`. But in your code you are assigning the value to `CGSize`.

Eg:

```
CGRect textRect = [_lbl_title.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
```

Sample:

```
   - (float)expectedLabelHeight
{    
    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(_lbl_title.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:14];
    CGRect textRect = [_lbl_title.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

    return (textRect.size.height+20.0);
}
```

Change your code in accordance with the above example.